# How To replicate from same database name on multiple site

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have a few dozens of sites (with replication enabled, and multiple satellite on each) where there is a standardized database (same schema), let's said its named "prod" everywhere.

I would like to be able to replicate every "prod" database on every distant site to a local (head office) prod-site1 and prod-site2 and so on, so I have a read only local replica of every database on every site.

But I have no clue on how to do that.

my first guess was : Is a proxy a solution ?  so I can map siteX->databaseY to a local prod-siteX ?

my second guess was to use option [--replicate-rewrite-db](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqld-options/#-replicate-rewrite-db) but it turn out that most of my databases have the same name. So it doesn't have lot of sense to write

```
replicate-rewrite-db=prod->prod-site1
replicate-rewrite-db=prod->prod-site2
```

or is there any way to signify a site in the equation ? like

```
replicate-rewrite-db=site1.prod->prod-site1
```

or maybe use server-id ? I dunno.

my third guess is to rsync every (whatever time) the binarylog (log_bin) for each site/prod-database so I can replay the activity log from one point to the other on the adequate database (prod-site1), but it is a lot of sync to do ... but looks like no other solution exist.

I am using mariadb 10.2 everywhere.
Thanks for your directions if you have any idea.

not sure if I am clear enough about this problem, do not hesitate to ask or comment.

Comment: Have you read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/

Comment: yes, I am using multi source on every distant site, but I cant see how to replicate activity_log from ipsite1.prod to  hereishead.prod_site1.

Comment: Maybe not exact with the same names, but some sort of [vitess shard](https://vitess.io/docs/reference/features/sharding) maybe.